# How to fix "Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules "

Tags: android

Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app's build.gradle file, remove references to `com.android.support` if you are using androidx.  Posting your app module's build.gradle file would be helpful if that doesn't work.

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone if the above solution doesn't work.
Enable AndroidX in your project gradle.properties file:
Add these lines:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```